# Modify new user welcome email

Tags: user-registration

Is there a way I could set up the wordpress new user welcome email to show up the password i've set up for the new user?

I want to manually set up their password and they can't change / reset it so when a new user gets registered, I want to show the password i've create along with their username.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can check the `send the user an email about their account` when creating an account

Comment: i check that but it doesnt show the password set @Buttered_Toast

Comment: Why do you want to 1) show the password and 2) prevent users to change it?

Comment: We have a page that will only be accessible by certain users for a certain amount of time so we don't want them doing anything else.

Comment: Why not create a specific role for those users? after the time was passed, change all thos users to a basic role

Comment: I don't care about their roles though. I need to just show their "password" on the welcome email. I am not wanting to do anything else. @Buttered_Toast